# Using grep to match all combination between substrings

Tags: grep

I have piped strings that are along the lines of:

```
(string start..) Enzyme: "ENZA ENZB ENZD ENZE" (..string end)  
(string start..) Enzyme:"ENZA ENZC ENZD ENZF" (..string end) 
(string start..) Enzyme:"ENZO ENZC ENZD ENZE" (..string end)
```

where I want my grep to output everything from start of "Enzyme" to end of second double quote, regardless of the value or quantity of what is between the two double quote (can be 1 to 20 enzymes and I don't know their values). The enzymes are always upper case alpha, but if more than one, there is always a space in between.

I have tried:

```
grep -o "Enzyme: \"(.*)\"
grep -o "Enzyme: \"[A-Z]\"
grep -o "Enzyme: \"[:alpha:]\"
grep -o "Enzyme: \"*\"
```

, but none of these return anything. I would be grateful for any ideas as to get what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Why use double quotes in double quotes?  Use singles as the outer.  The 1st needs no parens.  The 2nd and 3rd match only a single character and not spaces... the 4th is a glob and not a regex unless you mean to match strings of double-quotes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is checking `Enzyme:` followed by zero or more white spaces followed by `"` till next `"` is seen.

Using `-E` flag:

```
grep -oE 'Enzyme:[[:space:]]*"[^"]+"'
Enzyme: "ENZA ENZB ENZD ENZE"
Enzyme:"ENZA ENZC ENZD ENZF"
Enzyme:"ENZO ENZC ENZD ENZE"
```

With `-P` flag:

```
grep -oP 'Enzyme:\s*"[^"]+"'
Enzyme: "ENZA ENZB ENZD ENZE"
Enzyme:"ENZA ENZC ENZD ENZF"
Enzyme:"ENZO ENZC ENZD ENZE"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -o 'Enzyme: ?"[^"]+"'
```

Match `Enzyme:` literally, followed by an optional space, a literal double quote, anything that's *not* a double quote, and a literal double quote.

Answer (score 0):

Grep always outputs the whole match, which includes your ankers 'Enzyme: "' and '"'
To match the ankers but omit them in the output you have to use a postive lookbehind with the prefix and a posititve lookahead with the postfix of your desired output:

`grep -oE "(?<=Enzyme:\")(.*)(?=\")"`

for testing:
`echo 'Enzyme:"enz3 enz6 enz12 enz19"' | grep -oP "(?<=Enzyme:\")(.*)(?=\")"`

that said, I find it a lot easier to use sed in this case:
`echo 'Enzyme:"enz3 enz6 enz12 enz19"' | sed -r "s/Enzyme:\"(.*)\"/\1/g"`

`s/find/replace/` is the search&replace command of sed

Comment: according to my manpage -P is only experimental together with -z. Apart from that you are correct, I'll edit the answer

Comment: On the other hand without ERE the braces need escaping wich in my opinion renders the expression mostly unreadable

Answer (score 0):

To do this with grep you'd need GNU grep for `-o`:

```
grep -o 'Enzyme: *"[^"]*"'
```

Otherwise, using any sed in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ sed -n 's/.*\(Enzyme: *"[^"]*"\).*/\1/p' file
Enzyme: "ENZA ENZB ENZD ENZE"
Enzyme:"ENZA ENZC ENZD ENZF"
Enzyme:"ENZO ENZC ENZD ENZE"
```